# How to calculate percentage contribution in power bi

Tags: powerbi

How to calculate percentage contribution in power bi

[image]

I want to calculate percentage contribution on basis on rows
for eg create new column called "% contribution", in this column calculation will be 3904.49/29309.78 next row 8537.75/29309.78 and so on last column should indicate 100% contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple measure on the form:

```
% of GT = 
VAR _all_selected = CALCULATE ( [Measure], ALLSELECTED () )
RETURN 
DIVIDE ( 
    [Measure] , 
    _all_selected
)
```

In the ribbon, navigate to measure tools to set the percentage formatting as required.

Comment: What [Measure] indicates ?

Comment: Whatever measure you want to run the GT% for. You can e.g. replace `[Measure]` with `SUM('Table'[Column])` if that is what you are doing in your picture. Difficult to say based on the lack of data you have provided in the question.

Comment: Great i used the same and got desired output .. thanks man , could you please explain the code?

Comment: Then please upvote and mark solution as accepted :) Basically `ALLSELECTED()` "expands" the visual-row evaluation context to include all the visible values in the visualization. For each row in the visual, the total sum is calculated and stored in the variable, which forms the basis for our divisor. This measure will also respond to filtering. E.g. if you exclude `MORTGAGES`, all the numbers will update to the current visible total of the visual. Refer to this guide for more informaton on `ALLSELECTED`: `https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-allselected/`